# Holomorphic function: proving that $0 \leq f'(x)$ under conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open set with $\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}\neq\emptyset$. Suppose $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is
holomorphic with

- $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$
- $\text{Im}\big(f(z)\big) > 0$ for every $z\in\Omega$ with $\text{Im}( z )> 0$

Show that $f'(x)\geq 0 $ for every $x\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$.

I wanted to solve this by using the cauchy-Riemann equations but I did not get to the solutions. I first thought that it ment that if it does not have a imaginary part the one side of the equation will be equal. However this is not always the case I thought if you derive it?

Can anybody help me understand how I can apply these equations? Because I really do not know how I have to start this excercise...

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann should work. Show that $v_x = 0$ and $v_y \ge 0$ for all points on the real axis.

Comment: first doing the derivative through the reals gives you $f'(x) \in \mathbb R,  x\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$ and then writing the Taylor series at such $x$ so that $f(z)=f(x)+a(z-x)+O(z-x)^2$ and taking $z=x+i\epsilon, \epsilon>0$ one gets that $a\epsilon >0$ for small enough $\epsilon >0$ so $a>0$ hence $f'(x)>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $f(x+iy) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ we have that $v(x, 0) = 0$ for $x \in \Omega \cap \Bbb R$ and $v(x, y) > 0$ for $x+iy \in \Omega$ with $y > 0$.

It follows that for all $x \in \Omega \cap \Bbb R$
$$
 v_x(x, 0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(x+h, 0)-v(x, 0)}{h} = 0
$$
and
$$
 u_x(x, 0) = v_y(x, 0) = \lim_{h \to 0, h > 0} \frac{v(x, h)-v(x, 0)}{h} \ge 0
$$
and therefore
$$
 f'(x) = u_x(x, 0) + iv_x(x, 0) \ge 0 \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\forall x\in\Omega\cap\Bbb R):f(x)\in\Bbb R$, it is clear that $(\forall x\in\Omega\cap\Bbb R):f'(x)\in\Bbb R$. Now, take $x_0\in\Omega\cap\Bbb R$ and suppose that $f'(x_0)=\lambda<0$. Then there is a continuous function $\varphi\colon\Omega\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that $\varphi(x_0)=0$ and that$$(\forall z\in\Omega):f(z)=f(x_0)+\lambda(z-x_0)+\varphi(z)(z-x_0).$$Since $\varphi(x_0)=0$ and since $\varphi$ is continuous, $\lim_{z\to x_0}\varphi(z)=0$. Take $\delta>0$ such that$$|z-x_0|<\delta\implies\bigl|\varphi(z)\bigr|=\bigl|\varphi(z)-\varphi(x_0)\bigr|<-\frac\lambda2.$$Then, if $|z-x_0|<\delta$ and if $\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$, $\operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)<0$, since $x_0\in\Bbb R$,$$f(z)=\overbrace{f(x_0)}^{\phantom{\Bbb R}\in\Bbb R}+\lambda(z-x_0)+\varphi(z)(z-x_0),$$$\lambda<0$, and $\bigl|\varphi(z)\bigr|<-\frac\lambda2$. But we are assuming that$$\operatorname{Im}z>0\implies\operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)>0.$$